# Error with selenium for send_keys : str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to **scrape** with selenium; I followed the instruction but I have an error regarding "send_key" when I am going to send my username and password :

```
 runfile('C:/Users/thmag/untitled3.py', wdir='C:/Users/thmag')
    C:\Users\thmag\untitled3.py:20: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
      driver= webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options = options)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "C:\Users\thmag\untitled3.py", line 30, in <module>
        user_ele.send_keys('MyEmail@gmail.com')
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

My code is as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import  Keys
import pandas as pd
import time


driver_path = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

driver= webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options = options)

url= "https://healthunlocked.com/"

driver.get(url)

loginpage= driver.find_element_by_id("sitebar-login-button")
loginpage.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

user_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
user_ele.send_keys('MyEmail@gmail.com')
user_ele.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

pass_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pass_ele.send_keys('MyPass')
pass_ele.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: You forget initialize the `user_ele` variable, it's should `user_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')`

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing that error?

Comment: I initialized the user_ele, but I have still that error

Comment: Yes, the error is exactly for this line.  
  File "C:\Users\thmag\untitled3.py", line 30, in <module>
    user_ele.send_keys('MyEmail@gmail.com')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the placeholder, then send keys :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import  Keys
import pandas as pd
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

driver= webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

url= "https://healthunlocked.com/"

driver.get(url)

# closing cookies thing 
driver.find_element_by_id('ccc-notify-accept').click()

loginpage= driver.find_element_by_id("sitebar-login-button").click()

time.sleep(3)

user_ele = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
user_ele.clear()
user_ele.send_keys('MyEmail@gmail.com')

pass_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pass_ele.clear()
pass_ele.send_keys('MyPassword')

# submitting
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/form/button').click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

if you just want to login, you can use requests to send a post request

Comment: Many thanks, It works perfectly. Would you please ask me to help me to write a code for click on the logging button on the logging page?  I have tried to run the code but I have the same error for the logging button.

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi , i have updated the code with better way, since the other method didn't work while submitting

Answer (score 0):

Use options instead of chrome options and set user_ele.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

driver= webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options = options)

url= "https://healthunlocked.com/"

driver.get(url)

loginpage= driver.find_element_by_id("sitebar-login-button")
loginpage.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

user_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
user_ele.send_keys('MyEmail@gmail.com')
user_ele.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

pass_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pass_ele.send_keys('MyPass')
pass_ele.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I did what you comment, but there is still that error.